# C++ iterator для своего контейнера

Tags: c++, c++11, стек

Здравствуйте! Я написал свой класс-контейнер. И теперь мне нужно написать класс iterator, чтобы мой контейнер смог взаимодействовать с алгоритмами стандартной библиотеки. Написал класс:

```
class Iterator {
public:
    Iterator(T *first) {
        current = first;
    }

    T &operator+(int n) {
        return *(current + n);
    }
    T &operator-(int n) {
        return *(current - n);
    }
    T &operator++(int) {
        return *current++;
    }
    T &operator--(int) {
        return *current--;
    }
    T &operator++() {
        return *++current;
    }
    T &operator--() {
        return *--current;
    }

    bool operator==(const Iterator &it) {
        return current == it.current;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator &it) {
        return current != it.current;
    }
    T &operator*() {
        return *current;
    }
private:
    T *current;
};
```

Код в main:

```
Array<int> arr;
Array<int> arr2;

for (int i(160); i >= 0; i -= 5)
{
    arr.append(i);
}
for (int i(0); i < 180; i += 5)
{
    arr2.append(i);
}

sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

В итоге получаю несколько ошибок при сборке:

> error C2679: бинарный "-": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "Array::Iterator" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
>
> error C2780: void std::_Sort(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Diff,_Pr): требует аргументов: 4, имеется: 3

Comment: И? Сообщение об ошибке ясно говорит в чем проблема: вычитание итераторов не реализовано.

Comment: @AnT можете написать эти реализации в ответе? Я не совсем понимаю, в чём разница между бинарным и унарным "-".

Comment: @Vlad   `c = a - b;` - здесь минус бинарный, `c = -a;` - а вот здесь унарный...

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, что у вас неправильно в append, но итератор реализован неправильно. Бинарные операторы + и - должны возвращать новый итератор, а не объект типа Т, аналогично с операторами ++ и --. Скорее всего, должно быть примерно так :

```
class Iterator {
public:
    explicit Iterator(T *first): current(first) {

    }

    Iterator operator + (int n) const{
        return Iterator(current + n);
    }

    Iterator operator++(int) {
        Iterator tmp(current++);
        return tmp;
    }

    Iterator& operator++() {
        ++current
        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator - (int n) const{
        return Iterator(current - n);
    }

    Iterator operator--(int) {
        Iterator tmp(current--);
        return tmp;
    }

    Iterator& operator--() {
        --current
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const Iterator &it) const{
        return current == it.current;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator &it) const{
        return !(*this == it);
    }
    T &operator*() {
        return *current;
    }
    const T &operator*() const{
        return *current;
    }
private:
    T *current;
};
```

P.S. И про const не забывайте.